# Let $L:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator such that $L^3=L$. Prove that $Ker(L-I)\oplus Im(L-I)=V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator such that $L^3=L$,where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Prove that $Ker(L-I)\oplus Im(L-I)=V$.

I have no idea how to start solving this problem. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $V$? A finite dimensional vector space, a Hilbert space... ?

Comment: @Peter I've edited my question. It's a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Begin by taking apart what has to be shown. For example, to show that an element $x$ is in $ker(L-I)$, you must show that $Lx - x = 0$ or $Lx = x$. To show that $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$ you must show among other things that $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$. And so on. Then try to prove some of the pieces.

Comment: @HansEngler thank you for the advice. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the characteristic is different of $3$.
You know that $dim(Ker(L-I))+dim(Im(L-I)=dim(V)$.

Let $x\in Ker(L-I)\cap Im(L-I)$, $L(x)=x$ and $x=L(y)-y$ this implies that

$x=L(y)-y$

$L(x)=x=L^2(y)-L(y)$,

$L^2(x)=x=L^3(y)-L^2(y)=y-L^2(y)$.

You obtain $3x=L(y)-y+L^2(y)-L(y)+y-L^2(y)=0$ and $x=0$.

You deduce that $Ker(L-I)\cap Im(L-I)=\{0\}$ and henceforth $Ker(L-I)\oplus Im(L-I)=V$.

Comment: Shouldn't I first prove that $Ker(L-I)+ Im(L-I)=V$ and then prove that it's the direct sum?

Comment: @DraganZrilić there's no need.  Note that 
$$
\dim(\ker(L - I) + \operatorname{im}(L - I)) = \dim \ker(L - I) + \dim \operatorname{im}(L - I) - \dim[\ker(L - I) \cap \operatorname{im}(L - I)]
$$

Comment: @DraganZrilić or more specifically: if $U_1,U_2$ are subspaces such that $\dim U_1 + \dim U_2 = \dim V$, then $U_1 + U_2 = V \iff U_1 \cap U_2 = \{0\}$.